# CoffeeScript's Modulus Operator's Coercion

Tags: coffeescript

Why does CoffeeScript's `%` operator coerce its argument to a number?

```
coffee> '3' % 3
0
coffee> '3a' % 3
NaN
```

Comment: Yeah, it's not doing that for `==` comparisons! http://js2.coffee/#coffee/try:console.log%20'is%203'%20if%20%24('%23user_type').val()%20%3D%3D%203

Answer (score 1):

Because that's what the Javascript spec says; [§11.5](http://es5.github.io/#x11.5.3):

> 5. Let leftNum be [ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)(leftValue).